# Using <select> and <option> in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropdown, ng-options, angularjs-select

I have this anchor tag and i change my view depending on the date coming from the object. I am trying to change it to be a select option but it is not working the way i am doing it.

This is anchor tag syntax:

```
 <a href="#" ng-repeat="item in home.prData" ng-click="home.selectedPr = item; $event.preventDefault();
 $event.stopPropagation();">{{item.date}}</a>
```

I am trying to change it to be like that when i use select option

```
 <select st-search="{{item.date}}" class="show-tick form-control dropdown_custom_list">
      <option value="">- select a date -</option>
      <option ng-repeat="item in home.prData" value="{{home.selectedPr = item}}">{{item.date}}
      </option>
  </select>
```

i created an example plunkr to what i am trying to achieve:

[mycode](https://plnkr.co/edit/JR9y9cgGAiNTkCBXWixj?p=preview)

Comment: Try ng-change="home.selectedPr = item" on your select and use ng-model

Comment: See [AngularJS select Directive API Reference - Using `ngRepeat` to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select st-search="{{item.date}}" ng-model="selectedDate" ng-change="home.selectedPr = selectedDate"
 class="show-tick form-control dropdown_custom_list">
  <option value="">- select a date -</option>
  <option ng-repeat="item in home.prData" value="{{home.selectedPr = item}}">{{item.date}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Try adding a `ng-model` variable and on `ng-change` assign selected date.`ng-change` wont work without `ng-model`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">

  <select class="show-tick form-control dropdown_custom_list" ng-model="selectedHotel" ng-options="hotel.name for hotel in hotels">
    <option value="">select one--</option>
  </select>

  <div>
    Hotel name: {{selectedHotel.name}} Category: {{selectedHotel.category | json}}
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  // Code goes here

  angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', MainController);

  function MainController($scope) {

    $scope.selectedHotel = {};

    $scope.hotels = [{
      "id ": 1,
      "name": "some hotel 1 ",
      "category": [{
        "id ": 1,
        "hotel_id ": 1,
        "name ": "Cat name 1 ",
        "bnb ": "yes ",
        "simple ": "yes "
      }]
    }, {
      "id ": 2,
      "name": "some hotel 2 ",
      "category": [{
        "id ": 1,
        "hotel_id ": 2,
        "name ": "Cat name 1 ",
        "bnb ": "yes ",
        "simple ": "yes "
      }]
    }];
    // to make first  one default selected..
    //$scope.selectedHotel = $scope.hotels[0];
  }
</script>
```

Comment: i did but it is not working i don't understand why : [refer to this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/JR9y9cgGAiNTkCBXWixj?p=preview)

Comment: @HeshamElMasry, i have included a snippet w r to your plunkr. Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 7):

See [AngularJS select Directive API Reference - Using `ngRepeat` to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)

```js
angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
     model: null,
     availableOptions: [
       {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
       {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
       {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
     ]
    };
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
    <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.model">
      <option value="">- select an option -</option>
      <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions" 
              value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>model = {{data.model}}</tt><br/>
</div>
```

---

## Update

> I do understand this so what i have to do as [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/JR9y9cgGAiNTkCBXWixj?p=preview) is to match the model

Be sure to use the [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

For values that are other than strings, use the [ng-value directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue):

```
<select ng-model="mainCtrl.selectedHotel">
    <option value="">-select hotel-</option>
    <option ng-repeat="hotel in mainCtrl.hotels" ng-value="hotel">
        {{hotel.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

For more information,

- [AngularJS API Reference - Using `ngValue` to bind the model to an array of objects](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)
- [AngularJS API Reference - Using `ngRepeat` to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)
- [AngularJS API Reference - Using `select` with `ngOptions` and setting a default value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-select-with-ngoptions-and-setting-a-default-value)

Answer (score 1):

after i kept trying and searching i found a solution so i had to use an ng-model and assign it to my selectedPr as my example. and it worked

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" 
        title="Select period" selectpicker ng-model="home.selectedPr"
        ng-options="item.date for item in home.prData">
</select>
```