# Angularjs Add strange option into select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select

Hello I have the same issue

[Select Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783294/angular-adds-strange-options-into-select-element-when-setting-model-value)

i have strange option like this

```
<option value="? string:98 ?"></option>
```

Html Code

```
 <select  ng-model="vm.student" class="form-control">
   <option value="0">All</option>
   <option data-ng-repeat="src in vm.studentList" value="{{ src.Id }}"> {{ 
   src.Value }} </option>
</select>
```

and the default value go in the bottom doesn't appear I am trying many ways to fix this problem but unfortunately, no way work well

I hope to help me to fix this issue

thanks

Comment: Have you tried [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)?

Comment: yes, the same problem!

Comment: Can post test data/ relevant  code please?

Comment: ok sure i will do

Comment: [Can you check this?](https://jsfiddle.net/hsjt9kbd/19/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using `<select>` and `<option>` in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010863/using-select-and-option-in-angularjs/45011291#45011291).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ng-value` directive:

```
<select ng-model="vm.student" class="form-control">
   <option ng-value="0">All</option>
   <option data-ng-repeat="src in vm.studentList" ng-value="src.Id">
     {{src.Value}}
   </option>
</select>
```

For more information,

- [AngularJS API Reference - Using `ngValue` to bind the model to an array of objects](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)
- [AngularJS API Reference - Using `ngRepeat` to generate `select` options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#using-ngrepeat-to-generate-select-options)

Comment: Not Working with me

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using ng-options

By referring to  *[Madhan Varadhodiyil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7913153/madhan-varadhodiyil)*  example

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
       <select  ng-model="student" class="form-control" ng-options="src.Id as src.Value for src in studentList">
         <option value="">All</option>   <!-- value="" helps to remove void space from dropdown -->
       </select>                
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.studentList = [
        {
            "Id": 98,
            "Value": "Jon Snow"
        },
        {
            "Id": 99,
            "Value": "Mother of dragons"
        }
    ];
    
   $scope.student = $scope.studentList[0].Id; // I want Id:98 to be selected by default
});</script>
```

Hope it helps, Cheers!

Comment: in this example, the default value of selector will not be "All"

Comment: its just an example, you can keep 'All' as default by commenting `// $scope.student = $scope.studentList[0].Id;`

Comment: I tried but the same problem when I change from input1 the first option in input2 become empty strange option

Comment: I doubt the id which you are binding with `ng-model="vm.student"` is not in the array _( in this case it shows blank )_
I suggest you should check the 'Id' which you are passing.

Comment: No in the array the problem show in just one case when I change the value from input one